# Twitter API - Recognize Threads

Tags: api, twitter

I am trying to understand if there is an option to find out through the API if a tweet is a thread or not, it doesn't matter which API, search for tweets, get tweets, get bookmarks, any of them.

After searching through the API for hours all I see is there is a conversation ID but without getting for each tweet all the replies there is no way to know if it's a thread or not. I also tried to use edit_controls but that also led me no where.

Did someone find a way? Am I missing something? I noticed some people were able to do it so I am guessing it's possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, such a feature is not available at the moment and you have a dilemma, the first way is to get the last tweet of a string of tweets using API, which will chain to the main tweet, like the following output (lines 24 to 28):

[image]

But the second way is to check the comments of a tweet, and if the user-id of the commenting user is the author of the tweet, it means that you can use this code to receive the comments of a tweet:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(
    api.search_tweets,
    q="to:ZarchiMohammad",
    result_type="recent").items(200):
    if hasattr(tweet, "in_reply_to_status_id_str"):
        if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str == tweet_id:
            print(f"https://twitter.com/{tweet.user.screen_name}/status/{tweet.id}")
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammad that is what I thought... But wasn't fully sure. The issue is that the bookmarks are returning 800 results while the search is limited to 180 requests per user per 15 minutes. So basically for every user it will take me about an hour to check all...

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course, it was an interesting challenge for me, and if I find a suitable solution, I will definitely publish it here.